# MySQL default date() + 14 days, for a column?

Tags: php, mysql, date, default-value

I was wondering if the following is possible to do through MySQL or will it have to be done using PHP.

**Task - "Expiry Date"**

1. User enters product name
2. User clicks submit form button
3. Data is POST'ed and then sent to MySQL
4. Expiry date = date now + 14 days

What I am trying to achieve is a way for mysql to insert an "expiry_date" in a table column that will equal 14 days after the date the row was created in that table.

e.g.

```
product_name - foo
entry_date - 2012-02-01
expiry_date - 2012-02-15
```

I have a feeling it may not be possible to do in mysql unless using a stored procedure.

I am happy to do it in PHP however I was hoping if I could do it with mysql it would leave less scope for error in my system.

Thanks

Comment: You could use a trigger.

Comment: when you are inserting would'nt it be simpler to just add 14 days to your say entry date which i suppose will be NOW() and then pass it along with insert query??

Comment: @JaspreetChahal, no because I need a start date and an end date to varify that something has expired, as a failsafe for error prevention

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a table and set up a trigger for that table.

```
CREATE TABLE product(
    product_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    product VARCHAR(40),
    entryDate DATETIME,
    expDate DATETIME
);

CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON `product` 
FOR EACH ROW SET
    NEW.entryDate = IFNULL(NEW.entryDate, NOW()),
    NEW.expDate = TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 14, NEW.entryDate);
```

On each insert into the table, the trigger sets the `entryDate` to the current time and `expDate` to 14 days time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this by using `DateTime` methods in **MySQL**:

```
DATE_ADD(date_starts,INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

for example:

```
UPDATE events SET date_starts = DATE_ADD(date_starts,INTERVAL 14 DAY) WHERE event_id = 3;
```

For more details go [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: Thanks for this, never knew about the date_add() function! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
date = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

or as said, alter your table structure for that field (attribute for that field=) to "on Update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Answer (score 2):

you can try this this function

`DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 14 DAY);`

Answer (score 1):

According to this [source](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56835) you can't use expressions as a default specifier.

So not sure if it has changed since the bug was posted.

I'm not sure however why I assumed that the OP wants to define it as a default value.

Answer (score 1):

I believe MySQL won't allow you to use expressions in the default value. You might want to write a trigger.

MySQL does provide a TIMESTAMP datatype which can be set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP when a row is created or updated. You might find this feature *somewhat* useful:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    `Column1` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    `Created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

Once you're sure that MySQL is filling that column as expected, you can write queries like this:

```
SELECT `Created`, `Created` + INTERVAL 14 DAY AS `expiry_date`
FROM table1
```

Comment: I want to stay away from TIMESTAMP as its not as good as DATETIME, buts thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve that is just insert the value you want - without trigger or later update, eg.

```
 INSERT INTO <your_table> (name, expiry_date) VALUES ('foo', DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

Comment: Default in `CREATE TABLE`, not on `INSERT`

Answer (score 0):

I like this format better:

```
SELECT NOW()+INTERVAL 14 DAY
```