# Using Date_add() or add_time() function in create table itself

Tags: mysql, sql

How to create an attribute which takes current timestamp and adds some mins to it (eg: add 30 mins) in create table itself in MySql.

```
create table (order_time timestamp default current_timestamp,
              est_time timestamp default current_timestamp date_add(min,30));

shows syntax error
```

or while altering

```
alter table  orders modify est_time timestamp date_add(order_time,interval 30 min);

create table (order_time timestamp default current_timestamp,
              est_time timestamp default current_timestamp date_add(min,30));
```

Comment: As observed this is not allowed. You should read up on generated columns https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html but note that 'Literals, deterministic built-in functions, and operators are permitted. A function is deterministic if, given the same data in tables, multiple invocations produce the same result, independently of the connected user. Examples of functions that are nondeterministic and fail this definition: CONNECTION_ID(), CURRENT_USER(), NOW().' , You could use a trigger instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL default date() + 14 days, for a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190758/mysql-default-date-14-days-for-a-column)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614332/inserting-default-value-as-current-date-30-days-in-mysql

Comment: You haven't said when you would want est_time to be calculated , on insert , on update?

Comment: No way without using trigger?

Comment: Not if mysql is all you have, and think triggers (plural)

Answer (score 0):

If you want `est_time` to **always** be half an hour later than `order_time`, you can use a generated column:

```
create table orders(id int,
                    order_time timestamp default current_timestamp,
                    est_time timestamp generated always as (order_time + interval 30 minute));
```

Then you can insert values, with or without an `order_time` value, and `est_time` will be `order_time` + 30 minutes:

```
insert into orders (id, order_time) values (1, '2019-08-08 12:30:00');
insert into orders (id) values (2);
select * from orders
```

Output (as of 2019-08-08 7:43:04):

```
id  order_time              est_time
1   2019-08-08 12:30:00     2019-08-08 13:00:00
2   2019-08-08 07:43:04     2019-08-08 08:13:04
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a34b9377c7d985f8f091dd12d9911a4)